# Google Sheet Formula How to find UNIQUE Data Through Column Reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

[Image of formula not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QOB9.png)

I am trying to filter data by column reference

```
Not Work For Me =UNIQUE(A2:C6)
```

- 

What i want it shoutd be like [What actually i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg8Si.png)

```
I want find UNIQUE Data Through Column Reference B is Mo No.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

In this case a simple `UNIQUE` statement is not enough. You are looking for a function that takes in account only one column for your *uniqueness check*.

In this case `SORTN` is best suited for this job.

```
=SORTN(A1:C7,7,2,2,1)
```

#### Here is how it works:

- **n**: The number of items to return. Must be greater than 0.

*I have 7 rows so at most 7 results*

- **display_ties_mode**: A number representing the way to display ties.

*In this case 2: Show at most the first n(7) rows after removing duplicate rows.*

- **sort_column1**: The index of the column in range or a range outside of range containing the values to sort by.

*In this case is 2 as well. Since the uniqueness check is performed in the B Column.*

- **is_ascending**: TRUE or FALSE indicating whether to sort sort_column in ascending order.

*This is up to you*

Comment: thanx for asr my question that's work, but I found one issue which is, it's sorting my data by number count 1,2,3,4,5.... like A to Z condition 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg8Si.png
u can check reference again and it's that possible it will return my data without any condition like A to Z or 12345......